# How can I find only columns that contain specific chars

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I would like to get a list of columns that contain specific chars, for example I have this data frame object:

```
dat <- read.table(text = " TargetVar  Tar_Var1    Var2       Var3
 0        0        0         7
 0        0        1         1
 0        1        0         3
 0        1        1         7
 1        0        0         5
 1        0        1         1
 1        1        0         0
 1        1        1         6
 0        0        0         8
 0        0        1         5
 1        1        1         4
 0        0        1         2
 1        0        0         9
 1        1        1         2  ", header = TRUE)
```

How can I get a list of only columns names that contain the "Tar" in their name?
In this example the result should be: "TargetVar" "Tar_Var1".
Thanks

Comment: One way: `grep("^Tar", names(dat), value=TRUE)`

Comment: Thank you Arun, what does the sign ^ do?

Comment: It's a [regex](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html) metacharacter.  It makes sure the column name starts with `Tar`, so it wouldn't find a column named `VTar_robots_stink`.

Comment: The ^ requires that the search string return a match only if it's at the beginning of the string. For example "^Tar" would not return a match with "FirstTarget" but would return a match with your variable names. One other thing that might be useful to know: the ^ is also used for negation. For example "[^0-9]" will match any character except the numbers 0 through 9, while "[0-9]" will match only 0 through 9. So the meaning of ^ depends on context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grep` or `grepl` as in:

```
colnames(dat)[grepl("Tar", colnames(dat))]

## > colnames(dat)[grepl("Tar", colnames(dat))]
## [1] "TargetVar" "Tar_Var1"
```

This helps to understand what `grepl` does:

```
grepl("Tar", colnames(dat))
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Note that you can ignore case by setting `ignore.case = TRUE`.